# How to edit string “inline” from within the terminal without using any editor?

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, terminal

I am writing a program which does the functionality of a basic Linux shell. I am adding the functionality of upkey which we all know prints the history of previous commands on the terminal, using termios.h library. This prints the recent commands but i am not able to edit this. I am able to add character to this but on pressing backspace it does not edit the string. So how can I add this functionality.

Code snippet of this functionality.

```
struct termios T,O;
    tcgetattr(0,&T);
    char x;
    char y[80]={'\0'};
    char h[80]={'\0'};
    O=T;
    T.c_lflag=T.c_lflag&(~(ICANON));
    T.c_lflag=T.c_lflag&(~(ECHO));
    tcsetattr(1,TCSANOW,&T);
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,t_loop_var,loop_var=0,fd=-2;
    while((x=getchar())!='\n'){
        if(x=='\033'){
            if(getchar()=='['){
                if(getchar()=='A'){
                    if(fd==-2){
                    fd=open("history.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,0777);
                    }
                for(j=0;j<80;j++){
                    printf("%s","\b \b");
                }
                char K[1];
                while(read(fd,K,1)==1){
                    if(K[0]=='\n'){
                        break;
                    }
                    h[k]=K[0];
                    k++;
                }
                h[k]='\0';
                k=0;
                printf("%s",h);
                for(loop_var=0;h[loop_var]!='\0';loop_var++){
                    y[loop_var]=h[loop_var];
                }
                t_loop_var=loop_var;
                loop_var=0;
                //h will be the command to execute
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            tcsetattr(1,TCSANOW,&O);
            y[i+t_loop_var]=x;
            i++;
            printf("%c",x);
            tcsetattr(1,TCSANOW,&T);
        }
    }
    tcsetattr(1,TCSANOW,&O);
    //y[i]='\0';
    printf("\n%s\n",y);
```

Update: I got a suggestion in comments that a possible solution is using readline  library. And What I got from searching was this function `int rl_bind_key (int key, Function *function)`.This Binds key to function in the currently active key-map. Now how should I use this function to delete the character?

**Key for backspace is 8(ascii code for backspace). Now what should be the function ?**

Comment: This problem was solved before, have a look at libreadline

Comment: <O/T> `char K[1]` --> `char K;`, then just use `&K` where appropriate.

Comment: From the point of view of C, backspace is just a key - it's up to you to write the code that performs an action passed on someone pressing it. Or find some existing code/library and use that.

Comment: @yano although I agree, I've seen this "fake array style" before...

Comment: Probably want to check that `x == O.c_cc[VERASE]` rather than backspace. Or check for either.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks for your hint. I had a look at this library and what I found was `Function: int rl_bind_key (int key, Function *function)`, what i understood was that key should be backspace key and the function should be the deleting of command. Am I correct ?

Comment: Well I'm sorry, I never used libreadline myself ;)

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help !

Comment: With your keyboard in non-cannonical mode, you can test for char `127` (the `Del`) key which is what is generated by the Backspace key, then you simply `putchar (0x8)` (backspace), `putchar(' ')` to overwrite what is there, and finish off with another `putchar (0x8)`. This handles what is shown on your terminal, you must also correlate with what is in your history buffer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So you are basically saying that I should create a function and in that function i should simply do  `putchar(' ')`  and then add `putchar(0x8)` ?

Comment: Yes, this gives trivial backspace capability. All you are doing is issuing the `(bs)` char to backup 1, then outputting a space to clear what is there, then issuing another `(bs)` to put the cursor 1-space back from where it originally started. This erases a character and sets you up to enter something else. You still need to coordinate the bs with the index in your history buffer so it will contain the new edited command when done. You can do this all in a simple loop of about 5 lines. (OK, 10 lines, you must validate the input in ASCII `:)`

Comment: Yeah this seems to be intuitively correct. Thanks for your help!!. Just one more thing: Where should I place these functions in the program, at the starting ?

Comment: Well, that really depends on how you have factored your program. I use the "minimal editing" for taking passwords, etc. to allow the user to backup and correct a incorrect key, so wherever I need that capability, I just make sure my read loop is available. No magic. What I envision you doing is handling the up-arrow, then in that loop checking if something other than up/down-arrow is used, and in that case calling this minimal edit function passing the current hist command as a parameter, and orienting the current index at the *nul-character* to handle changes.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your help!!